# Como llenar un combobox en Netbeans con datos de una tabla en mysql

Tags: java, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2

Me podrían ayudar a llenar un combo box con los datos de una tabla en mysql. El problema es que la tabla tiene un `iD`, un nombre y una unidad. Pero al momento de llenar el combobox necesito que aparezcan los nombres; y al seleccionar uno, lo que en realidad necesito es el id de ese item. para luego ese id guardarlo en otra tabla donde es una clave foranea.
La tabla que quiero llamar al combobox es una de Tipo producto, donde estaran los tipos de producto, con su id, nombre y unidad. Luego en la otra tabla lo que quiero llenar son los Productos en si, donde se tiene el id del producto, el id del tipo de producto y su nombre.

a continuacion paso el codigo de mi base de datos:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema tiendapoo
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `tiendapoo` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema tiendapoo
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `tiendapoo` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`TipoProducto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`TipoProducto` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`TipoProducto` (
  `idTipoProducto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreTipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `unidad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTipoProducto`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`Producto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Producto` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Producto` (
  `idProducto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idTipoProducto` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`),
  INDEX `fk_Producto_TipoProducto1_idx` (`idTipoProducto` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Producto_TipoProducto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTipoProducto`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`TipoProducto` (`idTipoProducto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`Usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Usuario` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Usuario` (
  `idUsuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `clave` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuario`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`ProductoUsuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`ProductoUsuario` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`ProductoUsuario` (
  `idProductoUsuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUsuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `idProducto` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProductoUsuario`),
  INDEX `fk_ProductoUsuario_Producto_idx` (`idProducto` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ProductoUsuario_Usuario1_idx` (`idUsuario` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductoUsuario_Producto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idProducto`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`Producto` (`idProducto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductoUsuario_Usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuario`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`Usuario` (`idUsuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`Almacen`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Almacen` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Almacen` (
  `idAlmacen` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nombreAlmacen` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAlmacen`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`ProductoAlmacen`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`ProductoAlmacen` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`ProductoAlmacen` (
  `idProductoAlmacen` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idProducto` INT NOT NULL,
  `idAlmacen` INT NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` DOUBLE(14,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProductoAlmacen`),
  INDEX `fk_ProductoAlmacen_Producto1_idx` (`idProducto` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ProductoAlmacen_Almacen1_idx` (`idAlmacen` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductoAlmacen_Producto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idProducto`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`Producto` (`idProducto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductoAlmacen_Almacen1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idAlmacen`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`Almacen` (`idAlmacen`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`Salida`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Salida` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`Salida` (
  `idSalida` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `hora` TIME NOT NULL,
  `destino` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idSalida`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tiendapoo`.`DetalleSalida`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`DetalleSalida` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiendapoo`.`DetalleSalida` (
  `idDetalleSalida` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idSalida` INT NOT NULL,
  `idProductoAlmacen` INT NOT NULL,
  `cantidadSalida` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDetalleSalida`),
  INDEX `fk_DetalleSalida_ProductoAlmacen1_idx` (`idProductoAlmacen` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_DetalleSalida_Salida1_idx` (`idSalida` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_DetalleSalida_ProductoAlmacen1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idProductoAlmacen`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`ProductoAlmacen` (`idProductoAlmacen`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_DetalleSalida_Salida1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idSalida`)
    REFERENCES `tiendapoo`.`Salida` (`idSalida`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes tener en tu logica un metodo que llame la tabla y la lleves a un list algo parecido a esto:

```
    @Override
public ArrayList<TipoProducto> getTipoProducto() {
    ArrayList<TipoProducto> expenses = new ArrayList<TipoProducto>();

        Statement stmt = myConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tiendapoo.TipoProducto");
        while(result.next()){

            expenses.add(new Integer(result.getInt(1)));//id Tipo Producto
            expenses.addt(result.getString(2)); //nombre Producto
            }

    return expenses;
}
```

Cuando crees el control del combobox (eso suena a .net :) Jcombobox

```
List<TipoProducto> lstTipoProducto = new ArrayList<TipoProducto>(); 
jComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(ls.toArray()));
```

luego en el evento de action del combo

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    Item item = (Item)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println( item.getIdTipoProducto() + " : " + item.getNombre() );
}
```

espero que te guie...

Comment: me salta un error en la parte de expenses.add(new integer(resul.....

Comment: @DiegoChavez revisa bien los tipos de las variables si es integer o string